# Fetching web pages with proxy in Java-based web services

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, proxy

My web service is going to fetching some web pages with proxy:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
List<Proxy> proxies = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI(url));

URLConnection connection = null;
Iterator<Proxy> iter = proxies.iterator();
do {
    Proxy proxy = iter.next();
    System.out.println(proxy);
    try {
        connection = new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (!iter.hasNext()) throw (e);
    }
} while (connection == null);
```

However, the default ProxySelector always returns direct connection (no proxy). I have checked my IE proxy settings and set the proxy settings in the Java Control Panel to system browser settings.

Since the web service is invoked by a Tomcat server, maybe some configurations must be done in the Tomcat server?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

- http.proxyHost: the host name of the proxy server
- http.proxyPort: the port number, the default value being 80.
- http.nonProxyHosts: a list of hosts that should be reached directly, bypassing the proxy. This is a list of patterns separated by '|'. The patterns may start or end with a '*' for wildcards. Any host matching one of these patterns will be reached through a direct connection instead of through a proxy

Comment: But I do not want to specify proxy settings manually. Detecting and using system proxy settings automatically is just enough.